# Выровнять два блока bootstrap

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap

Есть два блока, которые нужно выровнять по высоте. Т.е. заполнить второй блок до низу.

```
<div class="row margin-top-5">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                      <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-block">
                              <h5 class="text-bold card-title">Your image:</h5>
                              <img class="img-responsive" src="img.png" style="width:75%">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Your information</h6>
                                <h6 class="card-title">Name: TEST</h6>
                                <h6 class="card-title">Surname: TEST</h6>
                                <h6 class="card-title">Age: TEST</h6>
                                <h6 class="card-title">Sex: Male</h6>
                                <h6 class="card-title">Married: No</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

В итоге получается что-то такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос в том - как заставить блок col-md-8 быть одного размера с col-md-4? Может, его можно как-то вниз растянуть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с `display: table;`:

```css
.row {
    display: table;
}

.row > [class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Вариант с `flexbox`:

```css
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: В первом случае накрылась вся страница. 
Во втором ничего не произошло.

Comment: Полагаю, "накрылась вся страница" потому, что классы `row` и `col-` у вас встречаются не только в этом месте. Просто добавьте свои классы этому фрагменту и, соответственно, поменяйте их в приведённом мной примере.

Comment: Демонстрация первого варианта: https://jsfiddle.net/rcrdvxqw/
Демонстрация второго варианта: https://jsfiddle.net/43qgn97a/

Comment: Либо я слишком тупой, либо не работает. Перекашиваются в итоге даже элементы без таких классов

Comment: По приведённым ссылкам можете увидеть, что всё работает. Как написал выше, добавьте данному фрагменту свои классы. Например, замените `<div class="row margin-top-5">` на `<div class="row margin-top-5 eq-height">`, а в приведённых мной примерах `.row` на `.eq-height`

Comment: Все получилось после суток возни) Спасибо)
Там были косяки мои личные

Comment: @myudasn, если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, вы можете отметить его, как верный

Comment: Отметил, спасибо еще раз)

Answer (score 0):

В bootstrap 4 эта проблема была решена. Потому как, перешли на Flex раскладку . А если вспомнить Flex, то высота всех Flex-элементов будет ровна одному максимальному по высоте !!!!!